# How many Lord Indra temples are there in India?

Tags: temple, indra, vedic-gods

Are there any temples in India which are exclusively dedicated to Lord Indra?

If yes, then where are those temples located?

If no, what are the reasons for Lord Indra not having temples dedicated to him?

Comment: In Vedic times worship of fire was prevalent. Temples came much later and at that time Indra lost his Vedic position of dominance. Might be this is the reason?

Comment: @Rickross even if there were later temples built that would have been fine too.

Comment: Most temples are dedicated to the panchamahadevatas and their various forms. Apart from that we have few navagraha temples. We don't have temples for the other deities.

Comment: Outside India, yes, the Tirta Empul Temple at Bali is there (which is mentioned in the answer). Apart from that there's a Temple of Indra at Ellora, complete with Airavata outside. It isn't essentially an "exclusive temple" as such, but can be considered as an Indra Temple. FWIW, I have clearly heard of stories about Indra temple being present in Tamil Nadu (but I can't verify them), and him being worshipped as a God of rain. I will add an answer once I find some evidence about the existence of Indra Temple in Tamil Nadu. (My comment could provide a gentle nudge in the direction of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about temple though read about Bali temple
But yes there is an Indrakund in Nashik dedicated to him , search on Google for that.

Comment: This looks one-line answer, you should expand it by adding some explanation and with adding some sources.